# Cannot start Adminer due to a 403

Tags: httpd, arch-linux, phpmyadmin

I have a server running on BBQLinux latest stable release, installed four days ago with pretty much nothing else installed or configured. I followed the [official guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Adminer) to install Adminer, and no matter what I do, I keep getting a **`403`** when trying to access it. Configuration is as follows:

**uname**

```
Linux cpu 4.7.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 30 19:28:42 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- Permissions inside `/usr/share/webapps/adminer` are `644` and its parent directories `744`
- There is no **other** `index.html` nor `index.php`

**httpd.conf**

```
...
DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
<Directory "/srv/http">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
Include conf/extra/httpd-adminer.conf
...
```

**httpd-adminer.conf**

```
Alias /adminer "/usr/share/webapps/adminer"
<Directory "/usr/share/webapps/adminer">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

-

```
me@cpu /srv/http % ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 18 22:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep 30  2015 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Oct 18 22:02 adminer -> /usr/share/webapps/adminer
```

> The soft link was added as a measure of attempting things to work

**/var/log/httpd/access_log**

```
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:06:31 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 985
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:09:06 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 985
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:12:13 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 985
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:12:15 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 985
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:19:25 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:19:25 -0500] "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:19:25 -0500] "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:19:28 -0500] "GET /fcgid-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 902
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:19:37 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:20:51 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:22:09 -0500] "GET /adminer/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 982
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:34:30 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:34:31 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:34:40 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:35:19 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:35:20 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
::1 - - [18/Oct/2016:22:48:11 -0500] "GET /adminer/ HTTP/1.1" 403 996
```

**/var/log/httpd/access_log**

```
[Tue Oct 18 22:34:30.221749 2016] [core:crit] [pid 24251] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:41886] AH00529: /usr/share/webapps/adminer/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/usr/share/webapps/adminer/' is executable
[Tue Oct 18 22:34:31.178160 2016] [core:crit] [pid 24251] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:41886] AH00529: /usr/share/webapps/adminer/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/usr/share/webapps/adminer/' is executable
[Tue Oct 18 22:34:40.682838 2016] [core:crit] [pid 24252] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:42240] AH00529: /usr/share/webapps/adminer/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/usr/share/webapps/adminer/' is executable
[Tue Oct 18 22:35:19.106504 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 24253] [client ::1:43458] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/webapps/adminer/
[Tue Oct 18 22:35:20.131063 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 24253] [client ::1:43458] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/webapps/adminer/    
[Tue Oct 18 22:48:05.459171 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24001] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Tue Oct 18 22:48:05.481813 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24001] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/7.0.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 18 22:48:05.481864 2016] [core:notice] [pid 24001] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd'
[Tue Oct 18 22:48:11.181295 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 28506] [client ::1:39946] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/webapps/adminer/
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You said: "Permissions inside /usr/share/webapps/adminer are 644 and its parent directories 744" So fix the permissions.

Comment: In addition to the permissions Michael pointed out, you can also get a 403 error when no DirectoryIndex is present and check for .htaccess files. Also you have both created a symbolic link in your document root and set `FollowSymlinks` and you also set  `Alias /adminer ...` as well. Normally you'd only need one or the other.

Comment: @MichaelHampton excuse my ignorance, but everything I've read so far says those permissions are fine. Mind specifying which should I set?

Comment: 744 is so obviously wrong that anything you read that contains it should be entirely suspect.

Comment: G-sus-crhist. Can you please say what permissions should I set in order for my server to work or are you going to continue shaming me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now. Thanks to @HBrujin. I only had to comment-out the alias on the configuration since I already had a symlink

**httpd-adminer.conf**

`#Alias /adminer "/usr/share/webapps/adminer"`

Please note that it was not commented, and it still didn't work **before** creating the symlink.

Hope this helps somebody.